# C# httpclient как выйти с сеть с определенного IP

Tags: c#, httpclient

Есть сервер линукс с 2мя внешними Ipv4 и и ipv6 с 64й подсеткой.
Как можно использую Httpclient отправлять запросы например с ipv4 с выбором с какого IP отправлять запрос во внешний мир, ну и такой же момент с Ipv6 как с любого Ipv6 который доступен  мне с подсети отправлять запрос во внешний мир.
Неужели для решения нужно будет поднимать 3proxy сервер.

Comment: Судя по тому что пишут [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23267): в .NET Core совсем нельзя (хотя [обещают](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23267#issuecomment-644454073) в NET 5 сделать), а для классического фреймворка есть какой-то костыль на базе BindIPEndPoint

Comment: IPv4 - это подсеть IPv6, то есть любой v4 адрес валиден для сети v6. Следовательно, зачем вам это? Например адрес `8.8.4.4` и `2002:0:0:0:0:0:808:404` - один и тот же адрес. А вы вообще уверены, что на интерфейсах у вас разные адреса? А вообще такие преобразования можно выполнять с помощью маршрутизации, а не proxy. @AK milestone 6.0

Comment: Хочу понять как 3proxy работает. Ну и запросы слать с разных интерфейсов  используя все имеющиеся IP

Comment: Через `HttpClient` - пока, никак. Нужно использовать старый `HttpWebRequest` - класс, чтобы забиндить IP-адрес. [Ссылка на пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4273521/6468198).